# Need help on creating a passphrase Generator

Tags: python, generator

I need to write a Python program that

- Reads a file: wordlist.txt
- Preview the document
- Randomly chooses four words from the file
- Displays those four words to create a passphrase

I just don't know where to begin, but I started with:

`import wordlist.txt`

Comment: `import wordlist.txt` isn't quite on the right track. `import` only works with other Python programs.

Answer (score 0):

Import is used to `import` Python libraries. You can't import file by `import`
Try this:

```
import random  # Import random library

with open("wordlist.txt", mode="r") as f:  # Open file
    file_content = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]  # Remove whitespace like \n \t or space
    print(file_content)  # Print wordlist.txt
    print(random.sample(file_content, 4))  # Print 4 random words
```

Comment: wow! thanks so much. you made it easy to understand with your comments